# showing two model items in yii2 as a radio list where a user cannot select both but one

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have a model having two items : is_normal and is_transporter

I would like to show both in an active form as radio list but i havent figured out how

This is the model:

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['reg_no', 'truck_category', 'added_by', 'truck_status', 'driver_name'], 'required'],
        [['truck_category', 'added_by', 'truck_status', 'is_normal', 'is_transporter'], 'integer'],
        [['added_on'], 'safe'],
        [['reg_no'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['driver_name'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        [['truck_category'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => TblChecklistCategory::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['truck_category' => 'id']],
        [['added_by'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['added_by' => 'id']],
        [['truck_status'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => TblTruckStatus::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['truck_status' => 'id']],
    ];
}
```

How can i use the two model attributes in active form as a radiolist

Comment: Can truck get both is_normal and is_transporter selected? Or only one of these?

Comment: a truck can only get one either is_norman or is_transporter

Comment: Only one type thats why i had thought of using radio list

Comment: So what is the point of having two attributes?

Comment: The point is during querying this model is used by others and using the two attributes makes queries faster especially if i have to check if its a transporter ill just check if 0 or 1 value is set,. And also when listing transporter and normal trucks

Comment: I can not see how this makes queries faster and on top of that you need virtual attribute now to handle the form radio button. I would do one attribute, let's say `is_transporter` - now listing transporters: `is_transporter = 1`; listing normal trucks: `is_transporter = 0`. One less attribute to take care of. Anyway, I'll add answer for two in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid having two attributes for this when one is enough but if you really need this here is the answer.

Prepare virtual attribute in the **model** to handle the radio button.

```
/**
 * @var boolean
 */
public $normal_or_transporter;
```

You need to add it in the **rules**:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        // ...
        [['reg_no', 'truck_category', 'added_by', 'truck_status', 'driver_name', 'normal_or_transporter'], 'required'],
        ['normal_or_transporter', 'boolean'],
    ];
}
```

Now in the **form view** add this field (assuming standard ActiveForm widget):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'normal_or_transporter')->radioList([
    0 => 'Normal truck',
    1 => 'Transporter'
]) ?>
```

Final step is to handle the virtual attribute. You can do it in the **model** again. We can use `beforeSave()` because `is_normal` and `is_transporter` are not in the `required` rule so validation pass without them being set.

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
        $this->is_normal = 0;
        $this->is_transporter = 0;
        if ($this->normal_or_transporter) {
            $this->is_transporter = 1;
        } else {
            $this->is_normal = 1;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```